# Why cant i texture paint blender 2.82

Tags: texture-painting

I have UV unwrapped. I have saved a new texture map. I have linked it all together with a new material on the model. Cant texture paint in texture paint mode.

It will however let me fill a whole new colour.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vXeXwqVf8ogOvbcXhoiZnARl7yz26xMk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You're using a texture which is black: remove it.

[image]